# How do you get a caldav calendar to show up in Reminders.app

Tags: macos, caldav

We have a working caldav implementation for our software to enable our users to access the contacts and schedules from iOS or Mac OS X.

My current headache is that the to-do calendar does not show up in Reminders.app. (It did show up when it was still in iCal sidebar.) To clarify: The tasks themselves are visible, but the calendar is not in the sidebar.

I'm pasting the property response here. Can anybody point me at something I missed?

```
  <D:response>
    <D:href>/dav/fg/todos1/</D:href>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <I:calendar-color/>
        <I:calendar-order>700</I:calendar-order>
        <B:calendar-timezone>BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//intevo.websolutions//TEAMBOX//DE
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Vienna
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20111030T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20110327T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
</B:calendar-timezone>
        <D:current-user-privilege-set>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read/>
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read-acl/>
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read-current-user-privilege-set/>
          </D:privilege>
        </D:current-user-privilege-set>
        <D:displayname>Aufgaben</D:displayname>
        <CS:getctag>"5109d85d95fece7816d9704e6e5b1279"</CS:getctag>
        <D:owner>
          <D:href>/dav/fg/</D:href>
        </D:owner>
        <D:resourcetype>
          <B:calendar/>
          <D:collection/>
        </D:resourcetype>
        <B:supported-calendar-component-set>
          <B:comp name="VTODO"/>
        </B:supported-calendar-component-set>
        <D:supported-report-set>
          <D:supported-report>
            <D:report>
              <B:calendar-query/>
            </D:report>
          </D:supported-report>
          <D:supported-report>
            <D:report>
              <B:calendar-multiget/>
            </D:report>
          </D:supported-report>
          <D:supported-report>
            <D:report>
              <D:principal-property-search/>
            </D:report>
          </D:supported-report>
          <D:supported-report>
            <D:report>
              <D:principal-search-property-set/>
            </D:report>
          </D:supported-report>
        </D:supported-report-set>
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
    </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
```

The Full exchange is here http://pastebin.com/aKN4Yw8Q

Comment: It might be useful to provide the full request/response exchange. For example, it is not possible to check whether your XML prefixes are mapped to the correct namespace.

Comment: True. I'll do that in a few hours as soon as I have access again.

Comment: full exchange is added as a pastebin

Answer (score 0):

The only weird thing that I noticed is the fact that for the todos response, you do not have a propstat for the missing properties (with a 404 status) while you do have it for all other calendars.

On the other hand, the client has a Brief header set to t (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-murchison-webdav-prefer ) so this should not matter...

Hopefully you will have find a solution by then but the Apple folks are well represented at Calconnect Interop events in case you are interested: http://www.calconnect.org/calconnect28.shtml

Comment: The missing 404s was a first attempt to find the culprit, when I saw that Baikal (SabreDav) didn't have them in their response.

Answer (score 0):

The client behavior changed between OS X 10.8 and 10.9. The version in OS X 10.9 is stricter in its interpretation of the privileges, although it may not be standard compliant in strictest sense.

I've traced a similar problem on our server and it seems that the culprit were the permissions returned in `<current-user-privilege-set>` tag. I don't know which privilege specifically causes the Reminders.app to show the folder, but returning the following ones seemed to do the job:

```
<write-acl/>
<write-content/>
<write-properties/>
<read-current-user-privilege-set/>
<read/>
<write/>
<write-content/>
<write-properties/>
<bind/>
<unbind/>
<read-free-busy xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
```

You may want to experiment with adding the individual privileges until the folder is displayed (or adding them all and then removing one by one). Note that the Reminders.app is lazy with refreshes, so you may need to remove and add the account for the change to take effect.

For reference, here is a full response on our task folder:

```
  <response>
   <href>/webdav/test@emclient.com/T%C3%A2ches/</href>
   <propstat>
    <prop>
     <displayname>TĂ˘ches</displayname>
     <resourcetype>
      <collection/>
      <calendar xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
     </resourcetype>
     <supported-report-set>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <acl-principal-prop-set/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <principal-match/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <principal-property-search/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <principal-search-property-set/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <expand-property/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <calendar-query xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <calendar-multiget xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <free-busy-query xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
      <supported-report>
       <report>
        <sync-collection/>
       </report>
      </supported-report>
     </supported-report-set>
     <owner>
      <href>/webdav/users/test@emclient.com/</href>
     </owner>
     <current-user-privilege-set>
      <privilege>
       <bind-item xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write-acl/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <unbind-item xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write-content/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <lookup xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <read-content xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <bind-collection xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <unbind-collection xmlns="http://icewarp.com/ns/"/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write-properties/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <read-current-user-privilege-set/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <read/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write-content/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <write-properties/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <bind/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <unbind/>
      </privilege>
      <privilege>
       <read-free-busy xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
      </privilege>
     </current-user-privilege-set>
     <supported-calendar-component-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
      <comp name="VTODO"/>
     </supported-calendar-component-set>
     <calendar-order xmlns="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">2</calendar-order>
     <getctag xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">&quot;1389952517:35&quot;</getctag>
     <sync-token>&quot;1389952517:35&quot;</sync-token>
    </prop>
    <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
   </propstat>
  </response>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these out after the weekend.

Comment: Didn't do the trick unfortunately. (I might need to clarify: The Tasks are visible, if you select all open reminders, but the calendar is not visible in the sidebar.)

Comment: @THgrendel I believe that's exactly what happened on our server, but a screenshot would be very helpful to confirm that we are on the same page. If you are interested I can privately share you test accounts on our server so you can cross-test if it works for you or not and what are the differences.